# TypeError for function argument in HTML + JS

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm working on a little website, and I'm trying to switch between different divisions.

My file looks a little something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script>
    
    const home = document.getElementById('home');
    const about = document.getElementById('about');
    const port = document.getElementById('port');
    
    function switchDivTo(divThing, otherDiv, otherDiv2) {
      divThing.style.display = 'block';
      otherDiv.style.display = 'none';
      otherDiv2.style.display = 'none';
    }
    
    switchDivTo(home, about, port);
    
</script>

<html>
  
  <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'> 
  <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'> 
  <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
  
  <head>
    
    <title> Website </title>
    
    <div class="navbar">
       <a class="active" href="#" onclick="switchDivTo(home,about,port)">Home</a>
       <a href="#" onclick="switchDivTo(about,home,port)">About</a>
       <a href="#" onclick="switchDivTo(port,home,about)">Portfolio</a>
     </div> 
    
    <style>
      
      
      
      .navbar {
        background-color: #333;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .navbar a {
        float: left;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 17px;
      }

      .navbar a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
      }

      .navbar a.active {
        background-color: #bf2ab3;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>
    
  </head>
  
  <body>
    
    <div id='home'>
      <h1>Home</h1>

      <p>
      website content
      <p>
    </div>
    
    <div id='about'>
      <h1> So Who Am I? </h1>
      
      <p>
      website content
      </p>
      
    </div>

    <div id='port'>
        <h1> My Portfolio </h1>

        <p>
          website content
        </p>
      
    </div>
    
    <footer>
      website content
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

Whenever I open the website though, it looks something like this:

[image: website]

and I get the error "TypeError: divThing is Null"

I'm unsure of what to do.

I tried having home, about, and port as variables and constants, that didn't change anything... I also tried moving around the script position a few times, it didn't do anything either.